# How to pass List box selected Items from view to the controller model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have a list-box with options. User can select all or select any one, so all i need is to bind the selected to the model on the controller.Now it comes as empty even though i have selected some.

I have populated the data to the List-box already. LoadAllControls method is in the index controller.

**Loading data to List-box. This works 100%**

```
public void LoadAllControls(myModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            string jsonReq = null;
            string jsonResp = null;

           //API call here
            jsonResp = JsonWrapper.JsonGET(jsonReq);
            List<Structs> listOrderTypes = DeserialiseFromJson<List<Structs>>.Deserialise(jsonResp);

            List<SelectListItem> listO = listOrderTypes.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = item.orderType.ToString(),
                Text = item.orderTypeName,
                Selected = "-1" == (item.orderTypeCode.ToString()) ? true : false
            }).ToList();
            model.orderTypes = new List<SelectListItem>(listO);

        }
        catch(Exception exx)
        {
            throw exx;
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "myController", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtfrom">Order Type:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.orderTypesIds, Model.orderTypes, new { @class = "form-control listbox", id = "orderTypeIdList", @multiple = "multiselect" })
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary " id="btnSearch" name="SearchButton" type="submit">
            Search
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>

}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Search(myModel  model) 
 {
    //Selected options comes as null  to the model

   //Some logic here
 }
```

**My Model**

```
    public class myModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> orderTypes { get; set; }
        public int[] orderTypesIds { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The name of the  model that am using is called "myModel" which have the orderTypes  and orderTypesIds . not sure if i have answered your question

Comment: Assuming `orderType` is typeof `int`, then the code you have shown works fine and `orderTypesIds` will be bound with the selected values. If its not working for you its due to code you have not shown us (and as a side note, remove the pointless  `Selected = "-1" == (item.orderTypeCode.ToString()) ? true : false` - that does nothing at all - the `ListBoxFor()` method sets the selected values based on the value of `orderTypesIds`, and also remove the `@multiple = "multiselect"` - the method correctly sets `multiple="multiple"`)

Comment: I think you are right. I will have to change this two line of code Value = item.orderType.ToString(), Text = item.orderTypeName. I will update you on what i have done

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for you explanation. I have changed value to ids and text to names and also applied the same on my view and it work fine. How can i load with pre-selected value ?

Comment: Set the value of `orderTypesIds` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. e.g. `model.orderTypesIds = new List<int>{ 1, 4 }; return View(model);` and then the options with values 1 and 4 would be selected